# Do we use the x-axis for defining polar coordinates?

Tags: vectors, coordinate-systems, polar-coordinates

**"To represent any point in a two dimensional space, you need two variables"**

right?

For example (using our good old friend, The cartesian coordinates) we can talk about any point in two dimensional space using two variables, $x$ and $y$.

All fine and good!

**Enter Polar coordinates.**

Now this system uses the renowned $r$ and $\theta$ where *theta is defined as the angle the vector makes with the x-axis.*

AHA! "Angle made with the x-axis" so we need to define what the x-axis is? so does that mean we are using **THREE** things to talk about a point?

ps: My doubt can be extended for three dimensional spherical coordinates but lets keep it simple.

Comment: $r$ and $\theta$ are with respect to a fixed point and a ray (or line) through that point. $x$ and $y$ are with respect to two orthogonal axes in the plane. Does this clarify your doubt?

Comment: oh! That does make sense! So we are using two facts but they aren't really $r$ and $\theta$ they are actually the point and the ray.

Comment: The two 'variables' are indeed $r$ and $\theta$, as you mentioned, analogous to the $x$ and $y$ coordinates in Cartesian plane. What I was trying to say was that we are not really using three things to identify a point; rather, we are using two things, $r$ and $\theta$, measured with respect to two things: a fixed point and a ray (or line) passing through the point in the plane, just like we use the two cartesian coordinates measured with respect to the two axes.

Comment: yeah thanks for the clarification!

Comment: Your “good old friend the Cartesian coordinates” requires that the $x$-and $y$-axes be defined somehow. By your reckoning, then, doesn’t that mean you’re using _four_ things to talk about a point?

Comment: hmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm. *insert pewdiepie hmmm* Now that I think about it... yeah..

Answer (score 1):

You need a designated origin and a designated line through that origin called the $x$-axis as a starting point to define a Cartesian coordinate grid as well. That's no different. The only difference is how you go from there to assigning a pair of numbers to each point in the plane.

The Cartesian coordinate system measures how far you have to go along the $x$-axis from the origin, then how far you have to go orthogonally to the $x$-axis to reach your point. The polar coordinate system tells you how far you have to go to get in a straight line from the origin to your point, and in what direction (relative to the designated $x$-axis) you have to go to get there.

So the moral of the story is that *once you have a coordinate system in place*, any reasonable coordinate systems in the plane (like Cartesian, polar or elliptic) will assign to each point a pair of numbers. But you do need a couple of parameters to fully specify any coordinate system.

Comment: yeah makes sense..

Answer (score 0):

In polar coordinates, we're referencing a particle by its distance from the origin and angle relative to a reference point. There's no reason that reference must be the $x$ axis. It can be the $y$ axis or the direction of any other unit vector.

Comment: Whatever axis you choose.. you still need to define that axis and that is an additional bit of information.